# Get currency rate

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

What I want to do is,

- to get conversion rate from this website (I have choosen xe.com
  because it supports needed currencies AZN <-> USD)
- If it's possible for example to send "5 AZN" and get what it equals in USD. URL looks like this: http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert/?Amount=5&From=AZN&To=USD

I grabbed the following snippet from [a blog](http://dickchiang.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-foreign-exchange-currency-with.html):

```
string xeString = String.Format("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From={0}&To={1}", srcCurrency, dstCurrency);
System.Net.WebRequest wreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(xeString));
System.Net.WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
Stream respstr = wresp.GetResponseStream();
int read = respstr.Read(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, read);
```

Now, this will return something like `XE.com: USD to EUR rate: 1.00 USD = 0.716372 EUR`

The problems are:

1. I have no idea what the variables `buf` and `BUFFER_SIZE` are.
2. How can I get an exact result, for instance send `5 AZN` and get the result in USD (as double)? http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert/?Amount=5&From=AZN&To=USD

Comment: I suggest forgetting about the `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`; use [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.80).aspx) or [`WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.80)) instead...

Comment: @codesparkle can you please show your idea on code?

Comment: just take a look at the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.80)#Y833), it's not rocket science

Comment: whatever method you choose to retrieve the html content, don't forget that's very unreliable. You have no guarantee that xe.com won't redesign its page layout and your whole code will fail. You should consider looking for a web service that provide such functionality.

Comment: consider using http://openexchangerates.org/ (AZN should be available from tomorrow on, currently unavailable because of "unreliable sources")

Comment: Dont use this method, becose www.xe.com simply dont allow getting rate (also the layout have change so this dont work)
you can use the paypal api -> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/

Answer (score 1):

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx

   buf is a byte[] array, which, once the method has returned, contains the data that you just Read.
   BUFFER_SIZE is the size of the data you want to read. If you want to read a single byte, BUFFER_SIZE=1. If you want to read one kilobyte of data, BUFFER_SIZE=1024, etc. Note that, if you ask for a too big buffer (e.g. asking for 1MB when the data is 1KB), it won't matter much. It will read a KB, and return.
2. Your final string should look like this, unless XE.com decides to change it:

   XE.com: USD to EUR rate: 1.00 USD = 0.716372 EUR

   You can use the String methods to strip things you don't need: The whole first part

   `(XE.com: USD to EUR rate:)`

   can be easily removed by just building a string with your data:

   `(string header = "XE.com: {0} to {1} rate:", currency1, currency2)`

   ,then calling `String.Replace(header, '')`. From there, you can call `String.Split('=')`, splitting at the '=' sign, then removing the currency part from the splitted strings (again, `String.Replace()`) and finally calling `Double.TryParse()`

Note: codesparkle's method is way easier, because you basically skip step 1. But XE.com are not providing an API: You have no guarantee the returned string will be valid, or won't change someday in the future.

OK, here's some code:

```
private double GetConvertedCurrencyValue(string inputCurrency, string outputCurrency, double value) 
{
    string request = String.Format(http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount={0}&From={1}&To={2}", value, inputCurrency, outputCurrency);

    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string apiResponse = wc.DownloadString(request);    // This is a blocking operation.
    wc.Dispose();

    /* Formatting */
    // Typical response: "XE.com: curr1 to curr2 rate: x curr1 = y curr2"
    // The first part, up until "x curr1" is basically a constant
    string header = String.Format("XE.com: {0} to {2} rate:" inputCurrency, outputCurrency);

    // Removing the header
    // The response now looks like this: x curr1 = y curr2
    apiResponse = apiResponse.Replace(header, "");

    // Let's split the response at '=', to retrieve the right part
    string outValue = apiResponse.Split('=')[1];

    // Getting rid of the 'curr2' part
    outValue = outValue.Replace(outputCurrency, "");

    return Double.Parse(outValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: A byte[]. A variable, like, byte[] data = new byte[1024];

But seriously, use codesparkle's method (with DownloadString())

Comment: I'm newbie to c#. Can you modify your answer based on codesparkles idea? Thx in advance

Comment: Please explain 2nd answer on code. Hard to understand for me. Really. Thx in advance

Comment: I get this ERROR when running code: "\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<!-- WARNING: Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use. -->\n<meta http-equiv"

Answer (score -2):

Deleted the old code. this one is by far the most accurate one
EDIT2:

```
string[] words = result.Split(' ');
Double newresult;

foreach(string i in words)
{
    if(Double.TryParse(i) == true)
    {
        if(!Double.Parse(i).equals(inputValue))
        {
            newresult = Double.Parse(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This should pretty much try to parse every word to double and ignore the double that equals the inputvalue(the number that needs to be converted).
this still isnt 100% accurate as if they add other seperate numbers to the string it takes that value.

Comment: This is a really, really, really bad idea. What if tomorrow, the message becomes 'XE.com : ' ? You just have a new space, and you'll be trying to parse '='.

Comment: @pikzen made it a bit better but you cant be 100% accurate if the string can change in the long term. Unless ofcourse u divide in words again. check if it can be parsed to double with Double.TryParse() then make it ignore the double which u wanted to convert and take the second one. that will most likely always work