# Argument out of range exception error in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

My method looks like that. [(Grabbed from here)](http://dickchiang.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-foreign-exchange-currency-with.html)

```
private void inetConvert() {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    string result;
    string xeString = String.Format("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From={0}&To={1}", srcCurrency, dstCurrency);
    System.Net.WebRequest wreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(xeString));
    System.Net.WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
    Stream respstr = wresp.GetResponseStream();
    int read = respstr.Read(buf, 0, 10240); // Error
    result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, read); 
    curRateLbl.Text= result;
}
```

The problem is, when app executes this application getting this screen after hanging about 4-5 seconds

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: if you had [followed my advice and used `WebClient`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384950/get-currency-rate-in-c-sharp#comment15006099_11384950), you wouldn't need to worry about buffer sizes.

Answer (score 12):

The buffer's size is 1024, but you tell `Read` that it can put up to 10240 (ten times the size) bytes into the buffer. As documented, it throws because

> The sum of offset and count is larger than the buffer length.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra 0 at the end.  Should be

```
  int read = respstr.Read(buf, 0, 1024); // Error
```

This is why you use constants in your app, to avoid those chubby finger mistakes.

```
private void inetConvert() {  
    private const BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];  
    string result;  
    string xeString = String.Format("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From={0}&To={1}", srcCurrency, dstCurrency);  
    System.Net.WebRequest wreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(xeString));  

    // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLEAN UP RESOURCES FROM ANY OBJECT THAT IMPLEMENTS IDisposable

    using(System.Net.WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse()) 
    using(Stream respstr = wresp.GetResponseStream())
    {
      int read = respstr.Read(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); // Error  
      result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, read);   
      curRateLbl.Text= result;  
    }
}
```

Also note that you're not closing your Stream object properly.  You might look into using a `using` statement to help manage resources from the stream.

But... here's how I would do this.

```
private void inetConvert() 
{   
    string xeString= String.Format("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From={0}&To={1}", srcCurrency, dstCurrency);  

    System.Net.WebRequest wreq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(xeString));  

    // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLEAN UP RESOURCES FROM ANY OBJECT THAT IMPLEMENTS IDisposable

    using(System.Net.WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse()) 
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
    { 
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8); 
        curRateLbl.Text = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: no. read source blog. They are 2 different variables int read = respstr.Read(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

Comment: What's `buf` and what's `size`? How much they need to be?

Comment: @epic_syntax - They can be whatever size you need them to be, but they should be the same in this case because you're attempting to fill up the entire array.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: There's no need to use a const here. Just use `buf.Length` in the `Read` call. Note that if you *were* to use a constant, it would be better named `BufferSize` - constants in C# aren't generally SHOUTY_CASE.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I totally agree, and thanks for mentioning it.  I used the const to make the point about fat-fingering, which may prove useful in other parts of the the OPs app.  Also note that the const came from the original source in the link provided by the user.